# some questions about tuple

Tags: tuples

I noticed that `Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]` gives the eight vertices of a cubic. `Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]` gives the four vertices of a square. `Tuples[{0, 1}, 1]` gives two points of a unit segment. is it just a coincidence? Or something deeper beneath it?

I don't know it is really a *Mathematica* question or a *Math* question.

Comment: Intuitive explanation: When "extended into another dimension", the points of the line segment (0, 0, 0) and (0, 0, 1) becomes (0, **1**, 0) and (0, **1**, 1). If you do it again for all the points, it becomes (**1**, 0, 0), (**1**, 0, 1), (**1**, 1, 0), (**1**, 1, 1). Each time you are just adding the value 1 for all previous points in the new dimension. You can see this geometrically too. Thus you produce all possible n-tuples of 0 and 1.